# Clicking a button of another application fails

Tags: c++, winapi

I am working with a dialog window, which has three buttons: "Save...", "Decrypt" and "OK". According to Spy++, each button has class "XButton". I am trying to press "Decrypt" from *another* application, so this is what i do:

```
    // "buffer" below contains dialog's caption
    hProgramWindow = FindWindowEx(NULL, NULL, NULL, buffer);

    // "caption" below contains string "Decrypt"
    HWND hButton = FindWindowEx(hProgramWindow, NULL, TEXT("XButton"), caption);

    SetFocus(hProgramWindow);
    SetActiveWindow(hProgramWindow);

    PostMessage(hProgramWindow, WM_COMMAND,
            MAKEWORD(GetDlgCtrlID(hButton), BN_CLICKED), (LPARAM)hButton); 

    // After posting the message, GetLastError() returns "5" (Access denied),
    // but the button is clicked
```

When `caption` variable has value "Save...", the "Save..." button is clicked (still GetLastError() = 5), the appropriate save dialog appears. But when `caption` variable has value "Decrypt", the "Decrypt" button is *not* clicked, no dialog appears. Any suggestions, why it can happen?

By the way, calling `EnableWindow(hButton, FALSE);` for "Decrypt" button (as well as for "Save..." button) works fine, the it becomes disabled, so that means that the handle is correct.

Comment: What is the Decrypt button supposed to do?

Comment: It is supposed to open a standard save dialog window to save a decrypted file (practically the same as "Save..." button, but it saves log, not the decrypted file).

Comment: Does it work ok when you run it from the first application?

Comment: Well, when I press "Decrypt" (or "Save...") with my mouse, it works fine. But when I try to click button "remotely" from my application, "Save..." works fine, "Decrypt" does not work at all. Technically, I cannot see the difference between buttons. But one of them works, another does not (?!)

Comment: Perhaps this has to do with which is the default button of the window. Can your OK button be clicked remotely?

Comment: No, both "Decrypt" and "OK" buttons cannot be clicked remotely (all three buttons have flat interface and pressing "Enter" or "Esc" does nothing).

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use the supported interface for automating a user interface: [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).

Comment: That sounds interesting! I will have a look at it and see if it can solve my problem. But, anyway, I am nearly finished with my task, and got only one button to click...